# Returning variable for .scheduledTimer to TableView Cell in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I have a `tableView` with a timer in each cell that runs when`tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is called. I'm trying to use a label (`cellName`) in a custom cell (`CustomCell`)  to show the timer incrementing. I'm using `#selector` in `.scheduledTimer` to call a seperate function named getTimer() to increment the value. Code as it is below.

*I've abbreviated this code to show only the relevant info*

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var time = 0


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let cell: CustomCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)! as!
    CustomCell

        var timer = Timer()

        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.getTimer), userInfo:nil, repeats: true)

        cell.cellName.text = String(self.getTimer())


    }

    func getTimer() -> String {

        time += 1
        return String(time)
    }
}
```

Two things:

1. My `time` variable is defined on the class level so that `getTimer()` can increment this on every `.scheduledTimer` refresh. I'd like to define it in `:didSelectRowAtIndexPath` so that I can run multiple timers at once. Is there a way I define this in `:didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, and maybe get the result through returning the increment from `getTimer()`?
2. Currently I am updating my `cellName` with a string returned from `getTimer`. This is static and currently thinking of ways that I can refresh it when .scheduledTimer refreshes. Should I be maybe passing `indexPath.row` to `getTimer` and updating it in the `getTimer()` function itself?

Comment: This syntax will never work. It is impossible to return a value from a target/action method. A solution is to create a custom table view cell class and put the timer in there.

Comment: Yeah you're probably right - I always knew I was clutching at straws this way. The implementation in my custom cell class should work fine. Will create the result as an answer here once I work it out for posterity. Thanks.

Comment: Edit your question and add the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic to the problem is not right. I'll give you a quick solution to your problem. Create two variables `timeArray` and `timerArray` in the class scope

```
var timeArray = [Int]()
var timerArray = [Timer]()
```

Put this code in your `viewDidLoad`. When creating the array, replace the count 1 to the number of cells in your tableview.

```
    timeArray = Array(repeating: 0, count: 1)
    let timer = Timer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.timerFired(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    timerArray = Array(repeating: timer, count: 1)
```

In your `didSelectRow` tableview delegate method handle the timer validation and invalidation

```
    if timerArray[indexPath.row].isValid{
        timerArray[indexPath.row].invalidate()
    }
    else{
        timerArray[indexPath.row] = Timer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.timerFired(_:)), userInfo: indexPath.row, repeats: true)
        timerArray[indexPath.row].fire()
    }
```

Add this function that will get triggered when the timer is fired.

```
func timerFired(_ timer:Timer){
    if let index = timer.userInfo as? Int{
        timeArray[index] += 1
    }
}
```

Finally, in you `cellForRow` datasource method of the tableview set the label text

```
cell.cellName.text = time[indexPath.row]
```

Don't forget to reload the particular cell when the `timerFired` function.

Comment: I get the error `Type '(UnsafeMutablePointer<time_t>!) ->  time_t' has no subscript members`...